# apply specific css element

Tags: c#, css, telerik

I am using a Telerik rad org chart.  Basically I want to apply certain CSS style based on a condition.

I have figured out how to just override a css styles:

```
.rocToolbar_Metro .rocToolbarButton {   background-color: #32b330 !important;}
```

But I can’t figure out how to do this conditionally via the code behind, so saying if `condition == 1` then apply this:

```
.rocToolbar_Metro .rocToolbarButton {    background-color: #32b330 !important;}
```

Else apply this:

```
.rocToolbar_Metro .rocToolbarButton {    background-color: #25a0da !important;}
```

I am planning to do this within the NodeDataBound event. Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Add JS on your page which will be changing button color and next you can use `ScriptManager` to fire this javascript from nodedatabound event.

**Add JS**

```
function setColor1() {
    $("#rocToolbarButton").css("background-color","#25a0da");
}
```

**NodeDataBound event**

```
protected void RadTreeView_OnNodeDataBound(object sender, RadTreeNodeEventArgs e)
{ 

    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "setColor1", "setColor1();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add css property without needing to write new classes to override the actual one

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var condition = 1;
  if(condition == 1){
    $('.rocToolbarButton').css('background-color', '#32b330;');
  }
  else{
    $('.rocToolbarButton').css('background-color', '#25a0da;');
  }
});
```

This works as follows:

```
$('cssSelector').css('property','value');
```